# Disadvantages of viewing a diffraction grating at larger order?

Tags: optics, waves, diffraction

If you are using a diffraction grating as a spectrometer you are likely to use high order, because you have a better resolution (as a result of larger dispersion??). But are there any disadvantage? I know that the pattern is less intense but that this can be compensated for, and I think I once read something about blurring but this could be wrong.

(p.s. I am mainly focusing on transmission gratings rather then reflection gratings).

Comment: First of all, you can't compensate for a loss of intensity. The incoming photons are all the photons you will ever get. An ideal grating will diffract all of these into the same order and there are no higher orders. Gratings that have significant losses of light into higher orders are not good gratings. Beyond that a real grating has a non-trivial groove jitter, which means that individual groves are slightly displaced from their ideal position, which results in non-ideal dispersion and a background. Both effects are typically stronger in higher orders. In short: don't use it like that!

Comment: "I know that the pattern is less intense but that this can be compensated for."  This is way too blase of a statement.  When working in optics you should never throw away signal photons unless you have a very good reason for doing so.  The only way to compensate later is to amplify the signal, but amplifiers are noisy and before you know it your SNR is near zero.

Comment: With echelle gratings, you deliberately work in high orders and use cross-dispersion to separate the overlapped orders. With ordinary gratings, even if blazed, you work in low orders in order to avoid the order overlap problem. With transmission gratings, such as my 200 l/mm transmission grating blazed into first order, it really only makes sense to work in that blazed order.